# Limit of postgresql for building apps

Tags: postgresql, mern

in the last few months i've learned the MERN stack, i really loved it and i'm gonna ket getting better at it, but i know that, when it comes to get hired an getting a job, in the backend, it's important to know another DB'S besides mongoDB, so, i started learning postgresql and i just don't get some things about it

Is there a limit of size for your database in postgresql? in Mongodb they would give you 500mb for free, and if you want more size in your DB you have to pay for it monthly or whatever, is postgresql free and, do i have to pay for more space in the postgresql ?

I know it's basic stuff, so, don't bully me (; and thank you for your time !

Comment: Postgres is a database sytem, not a hosting service. Your Question is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I get it, that's all i wanted to know

Comment: Check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/limits.html A single database server supports 4 billion databases. Each database has a maximum of 1.4 billion relations (tables and other stuff) and each table has a default maximum size of 32TB, but 128TB is also possible. Lets say 100 million tables in a single database, each table 128TB in size, that would be an impressive database. So yes, there is a limit, but one you have to worry about.

Comment: That's huge..., damn i haven't even used the 500mb that mongo give you LOL
Thanks for asnwering me